# Post-hoc analysis on Friedman's test

Tags: r, nonparametric, post-hoc

I am using a Friedman's test with post-hoc analysis. I am using the function `friedman.test.with.post.hoc` available for [R software](http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/02/post-hoc-analysis-for-friedmans-test-r-code/).

Lets say we have 6 wines and we want an ordered list of the wines according to the judges' rates (best wine, ... ,worst wine).

So, we perform the Friedman test. Suppose $p < \alpha$, we reject the null hypothesis. In other words, there is a significant difference between the wines given the judges' rates. In order to identify which wines are different, we run the post-hoc analysis. By running the post-hoc test, we have that there is only significant difference between the pairs: Wine A/Wine C and Wine A/Wine D.

Given that, how do you conclude the order of the wines? Should I use any other tools?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think there is any magic statistical tricks to sprinkle on this to tell you the order between Wine C and D.  Probably the difference is too small to detect for the given sample size.  the remedy is "Get more data!"  I hope you made the appropriate multiplicity adjustments for conducting several pairwise tests.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I wish getting more data was as easy as saying that :) I guess that, for now, I don't have enough evidence to say that there is different between the wines, even though the Friedman test says so.